# nodejs trouble with interface expands other. Methods from new interface Error: is not a function

Tags: node.js, inheritance, interface

I have a problem with a specific interface/implementation that bases on a general interface and implementation. All leads to the error, that the methods defined in the specific interface/implementation are not recoquenized and interpreteted as "is not a function". Here the situation:
I want to get repositories from a general generic method:

```
    public getRepository<T>(entityClass: new () => T): IEntityRepository<T> {
        const entityName = entityClass.name;

        if (this.repositories[entityName]) {
          return this.repositories[entityName];
        }

        const repository = new BaseEntityRepository<T>(
          entityClass,
          this.dataSource,
          this.logger,
        );

        this.repositories[entityName] = repository;

       return repository;
    }
```

To do so i have the interface IEntityRepository:

```
    import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';

    export interface IEntityRepository<T> {
      dataSource: DataSource;

      createOrUpdate(entity: T): Promise<T>;
      count(): Promise<number>;
    }
```

And The BaseEntityRepository class that implements the interface:

```
    export class BaseEntityRepository<T> implements IEntityRepository<T> {
      public dataSource: DataSource;
      protected repository: Repository<T>;
      protected logger: LoggerService;

      constructor(
        entityClass: new () => T,
        dataSource: DataSource,
        logger: LoggerService,
      ) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.repository = this.dataSource.manager.getRepository(entityClass);
        this.logger = logger;
      }

      public async createOrUpdate(entity: T): Promise<T> {
        if (!entity) {
         throw new Error('Save process called with uninitiated value');
        }
        return this.dataSource.transaction(async () => {
          return await this.repository.save(entity);
        });
      }

     public async count(): Promise<number> {
       const entities = await this.dataSource.transaction(async () => {
         return this.repository.find();
       });

       return entities.length;
     }
   }
```

Now I want to introduce a IUserRepository that expands the IEntityRepository and hast some more functionality to work with a user:

```
    export interface IUserRepository extends BaseEntityRepository<User> {
      getUserByUsername(username: string): Promise<User>;
    }
```

Und die Implementierung:

```
    export class UserRepository
      extends BaseEntityRepository<User>
      implements IUserRepository
    {
      constructor(
        entityClass: new () => User,
        dataSource: DataSource,
        logger: LoggerService,
      ) {
        super(entityClass, dataSource, logger);
      }

      public async getUserByUsername(username: string): Promise<User> {
        return this.dataSource.transaction(async () => {
          return await this.repository.findOne({
            where: { Username: username.toLowerCase() },
          });
        });
      }
    }
```

If I try to use that in this way:

```
const userRepository = getRepository(
      User,
    ) as IUserRepository; // getRepository return IEntityRepository so cast to IUserRepository
const user = userRepository.getUserByUsername('testuser'); // <-- getUserByUsername is not a function
```

What is wrong in my construction? Normally i would suggest that the "as IUserRepository" casts the IEntityRepository to the expanded Interface and the usage of the method defined in it are accessible.

I also tried to cast the userRepository to UserRepository ("as UserRepository") which also not leads to the expected functionallity.